# What test is appropriate for a continuous dependent variable and 2 independent variables (one categorical and one continuous)?

Tags: multiple-regression, categorical-data, linear-model, continuous-data

I have fish data from 2 sites and am looking to see if there is a difference in some hormone concentrations (continuous) between the sites. However, it turned out the size of the fish differed between sites so I also want to include this in my model, leaving me with one categorical (2 levels) and one continuous independent variable.

So far I have made linear models and used a multiple linear regression but now I'm wondering if that is the right thing to do when one of the independent variables is categorical?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, multiple linear regression is appropriate here. It would work even if there were only categorical predictors, because an ANOVA is just a linear regression.